# Fourier transform of frequency modulation in the case of an arbitrary modulator

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've done quite a bit of research recently trying to understand the spectra of frequency-modulated signals. There's quite a lot of information about the simple case, having carrier frequency $f_c$ and modulating frequency $f_m$:

$$\sin(2\pi f_c t + I \sin (2\pi f_m t))$$

However, I am curious about the more general case:

$$\sin(2\pi f_c t + f(t))$$

I'm curious about the case in which very few assumptions are made about the function $f$. I'd also prefer to know about the exact solution, rather than applicable numerical methods.

Comment: Take $f$ (locally) band-limited and write $e^{i f(t)} = \sum_n b_n h(a_n (t-t_n)) e^{i \omega_n t}$ where $h$ is a window, its FT is $\sum_n  \frac{b_n}{|a_n|}\hat{h}(\frac{\omega - \omega_n}{a_n}) e^{i t_n (\omega-\omega_n)}$

Comment: @reuns could you be a little more clear about how that answers the question?